# Authorization extensions for ServiceStack

Tags: servicestack

Is there any (or going to be any) built in support for declaratively securing (i.e. using attributes) REST services for oAuth2?

I would like to specify that the REST services of my SS web service can only be accessed by a client if they specify the oAuth2 'Authorization' header in their request to the service.

I don't want my service to provide authentication to my clients (i.e. no AuthFeature). Clients need to have already done authentication with a oAuth service (i.e. facebook etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `[Authenticate]` attribute on your Service ensures that only authenticated clients have access.

The [Authentication wiki](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Authentication-and-authorization) explains how to initialize ServiceStack's built-in **AuthFeature** to specify only the providers you want to allow clients to authenticate with, e.g. You can ensure clients can only Authenticate with either **LinkedIn** or **Google** OAuth2 providers with:

```
var appSettings = new AppSettings();            //Access Web.Config AppSettings
Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(() => new CustomUserSession(), 
  new IAuthProvider[] {
    new GoogleOAuth2Provider(appSettings),      //Sign-in with Goolge OAuth2        
    new LinkedInOAuth2Provider(appSettings),    //Sign-in with LinkedIn OAuth2        
}));
```

*Note: OAuth2 requires the additional [ServiceStack.Authentication.OAuth2](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack.Authentication.OAuth2/) NuGet package and Web.Config settings, see [Auth docs](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Authentication-and-authorization) for more info.*

#### Using Request Filters

You can also enforce specific requirements for client requests by a [Global Request Filter](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Request-and-response-filters) or opt-in [Request Filter Attributes](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Filter-attributes), e.g:

```
this.RequestFilters.Add((httpReq, httpRes, requestDto) => {
    var authHeader = httpReq.Headers[HttpHeaders.Authorization];
    if (!IsValidAuthHeader(authHeader)) {
        httpRes.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
        httpRes.StatusDescription = "Authentication is required";
        httpRes.EndRequest();
    }
});
```

#### More Service Restrictions

Also related are the [Security](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Security) docs describes how you can declaratively restrict services using the `[Restrict]` attribute.

Comment: Thanks, the Global Request Filter might be the way to go, as I don't want to handle authentication by the service itself. So, using the request filter, are there library methods I could use to (a) validate the authorization header is a valid oAuth2 one and not expired, and (b) how to extract the identity of the authorized user?

Comment: @JezzSantos a) Nope, once you've authenticated with remote OAuth2 server it's disconnected from its origin. You'll have to find out from each OAuth2 server if they provide a service to validate existing tokens. b) See [Accessing typed Session](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Sessions#accessing-typed-session) in the Session docs.